# AngularJS ngRoute updating URL correctly but not injecting template into ng-View

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

I am having difficulty getting my Angular routing to work on my mobile app (no errors appear in console when running). Here is the index. html file (with a div and ng-view)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>index</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script>
    console.log("Setting jQuery from WL");
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ; </script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <!-- SchedTek Header Bar -->
      <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
        <h1 class="title">SchedTekT</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <!-- Content box to inject HTML pages -->
        <div ng-view>
        </div>

      <!-- Footer tab menu -->
      <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-href="#calendar" id="calendarTab">
            My Calendar
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-href="#group" id="groupTab">
            My Groups
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item tab-item-active" ng-href=#events id="eventTab">
            My Events 
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-href="#settings" id="settingsTab">
            Settings
        </a>
      </div>

      <script src="js/wlInit.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now, the tab buttons with ng-href correctly change the URL but the route in app.js is not working properly. Here is app.js

```
    // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var App = angular.module('App', ['ionic', 'ngRoute']);

App.config(['$routeProvider',

        function($routeProvider)
        {
        $routeProvider

        //route to account page
        .when('/account',
        {
            templateURL:'pages/account.html',
            controller: 'accountController'
        })

        //route to events page
        .when('/events',
        {
            templateURL: 'pages/main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        //route to calendar page
        .when('/calendar',
        {
            templateURL: 'pages/calendar.html',
            controller: 'calendarController'
        })

        //route to group page
        .when('/group',
        {
            templateURL: '/pages/group.html',
            controller: 'groupController'
        })

        //route to specific group info
        .when('/group/:groupName',
        {
            templateURL:'pages/groupoverview.html',
            controller: 'groupIdController'
        })

        //route to settings page
        .when('/settings',
        {
            templateURL:'pages/settings.html'
        })

        //default to events
        .otherwise({
            templateURL: 'pages/events.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        });
    }
]);

App.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'main controller stuffs';
});
App.controller('accountController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'account controller stuffs';
});
App.controller('calendarController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'calendar controller stuffs';
});
App.controller('groupController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'group controller stuffs';
});
App.controller('groupIdController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'specific group controller stuffs';
});
```

just for example, the groups.html page looks like this

```
<h1> Placeholder for group </h1>
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

and pressing the tab generates a URL (in browser preview mode) goes from

(HostName):SchedTek/apps/services/preview/SchedTek/common/1.0/default/index.html

to

(HostName):SchedTek/apps/services/preview/SchedTek/common/1.0/default/index.html#/calendar
but none of the group.HTML template was injected into the div in index.html

and just so you can get an overview of the folder layout, 
[folder layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjRD3.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried different combinations of added "/" to template paths, moving around the  tags, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the wlinit file too?

Comment: If you are using tabs - could you not just load the content when you click on the tab as a template file either as a directive or using `ng-include` rather than using routes? Conceptually tabs are used for loading content on a view rather than changing routes in an application.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add ng-app to your html

In the html tag add

```
<html ng-app="App">
```

Comment: I had already bootstrapped angular in the wlinit.js file, but removing that and adding <html ng-app="App"> did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem where my pages were actually navigating on the address bar but the views were not loading.

Place the below code on the html element

That would ensure that other pages would reference your ngRoute functionalities